# Travel insurance for Schengen visa (for a Filipino couple)

Tags: visas, schengen, insurance, filipino-citizens

I'm having a hard time finding a travel insurance for my parents-in-law. They are from The Philippines and they will be visiting us 5 months in UK and 1 month in Schengen area.

I found two travel insurance from Filipino banks. HSBC (which requires their credit card) and BDO. HSBC is discarded because of the process of requesting a credit card, BDO is our option at the moment, although where not yet confirmed, and we want to have a backup option.

Anything I found in Google is either very expensive or just for UK Residents.

EDIT: Looking at [@toy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4022/toy)'s answer I can see the annual trip cover multiple trips in 1 year (up to 1 month per trip).

My question now is. If We are in UK and we take a ferry to Spain, does it count as a new trip? When we are back in UK, and then for example we go to Germany, does it count as another trip? How do they define "trip"? Do you have to go back to origin (Philippines in this case) to count as a new trip?

Comment: You would have to check the contract itself but usually you need to provide an address/permanent residence and that's what they use to define a trip, whether you are covered, etc. As long as you don't come back to this address (presumably for your parents in law, it would be where they live in the Philippines), that's all one trip. Depending on their status in the UK, it might be better to get insurance there, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used [Bupa](https://global.ihi.com/Travel+Insurance.aspx) before. They are not too bad and it's around 100 USD for an annual trip, and it's worldwide.

Comment: What is the difference between annual travel and single trip? because with Annual Travel is less than £300 but Single trip (6 months) is more than £1000.. I don't get it.

Comment: I'm guessing it's like buying in bulk. So, you will stick with them for long term.

Comment: I found the difference. See my edited question to see if you can help me with that. Thanks!